# Javascript code to separate first and last name from a fullname string input

Tags: javascript, string

I am working on a simple javascript code for practice and for some reason it isnt working correctly.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script>
    var str,len,toS,first,last,output;
    function handling() {
        str = document.getElementById("box").value;
        len = str.len;
        toS = str.indexOf(" ");
        first = str.substr(0,toS);
        last = str.substr(toS+1,len-toS-1);

        output = "Hello Mr."+str+"<br>"+"Your first name is "+first+"<br>"+"Your last name is "+last+"<br>";
        document.getElementById("para").innerHTML=output;
    }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <p>Enter your full name</p>
    <textarea rows="20" cols="20" id="box"></textarea>
    <button onclick="handling();">Press button</button>
    <p id="para"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

For input:James Smith

The output is:

Hello Mr.James Smith

Your first name is James

Your last name is

Without properly displaying the last name.I kept rechecking the code and I dont think I made a mistake in it. So why isnt the last name being output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this

```
last=str.substr(toS+1,len-toS-1);
```

to this

```
last=str.substr(toS+1,len);
```

**UPDATE**

Above solution is not the best - after you comment i check [definition of substr](https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencje/Obiekty/String/substr) and its second parameter is number of characters (I put total string length wich is acceptable however not 100% satisfyable for js purists). So te problem was in line

```
len = str.len;
```

which **@tevemadar** mention in his answer. So in your code `len = str.len = null` you get `len-toS-1 = 0-toS-1 < 0` (so less than zero characters to substract - this mean that `last=""` as result). So it should be

```
len = str.length
```

Comment: The lecturer used var surname = myname.substr(spos+1,len-spos-1);
and it worked correctly. I also know other ways of doing this, I just want to know why isnt THIS method working?

Answer (score 0):

I think is better and shorter using [String.prototype.split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split):

```js
let str = "john smith";

str = str.split(" ");//<-- returns an array object
let first = str[0];
let last = str[1];

console.log(first);
console.log(last);
```

Keep in mind this and those solutions are only valid if the input have only two words.

Comment: I know about split , but I want to understand why is the method above not working? Not how to make it work.

Comment: Your code didn't work because len = str.len; should be len = str.length;

Answer (score 0):

```js
var str = "Hello Mr.{0} {1}<br>Your first name is {0}<br>Your last name is {1}<br>";
var fullname = "Walter Chapilliquen";
var output = str.replace(/\{(\d+)\}/g, function(a, i){
 return fullname.split(" ")[i]
});

document.write(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

`len = str.len;` is the culprit here. It should be `len = str.length;`, because that ([`length`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/length)) is what [`String`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String)s have.